# Statistics for DPDK interfaces

Tags: dpdk

I want to get RX/TX statistics like bytes or packets sent/received for DPDK enabled interfaces. Similar to data present in the /proc/net/dev file. How can I get this?

I tried the command

```
./dpdk-procinfo -- --stats
```

But I get the following error.

[image]

The command that I use for the primary application.

```
./tas --ip-addr=10.0.0.1/24 --shm-len=1073741824 --dpdk-extra="-w 01:00.1"  --fp-cores-max=4
```

I get the following output on ldd

[image]

Comment: it is clear, the secondary `dpdk-procinfo` is not connecting with primary. Please check the comments in answer and update the ticket.

Comment: Ashwin waiting for your update if it is option1 or option2

Comment: Ashwin still waiting for your update

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Updated. @VipinVarghese

Comment: updated and waiting

Comment: please accept and upvote as required.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] based on debug session with Ashwin, it is been found PRIMARY application is compiled `DPDK-19.11` while procinfo is run with `DPDK-17.11.4`. Running with the right version for primary-secondary is working with `l2fwd`. Application has CFLAGS and LDFLAGS cleanup to be done. Suggested the same

Solution: always run dpdk-procinfo with the same version as primary.

I humbly request you to go through `http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html`. There are API `rte_eth_stats_get` and `rte_eth_get_xstats` which does the job for you. These can be invoked in the primary and secondary application of DPDK.

But if you are looking for a ready-made solution please take a look into dpdk-procifno application. The binary for the target is present in the `target folder/app` while the source code is present in `dpdk-root/app/procinfo`.

quick way to test the same is by referring to `https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-18.08/tools/proc_info.html`. the sample command line can be `./dpdk-procinfo -- --stats` and `./dpdk-procinfo -- --xstats`.

[EDIT]
as per the comment, if primary is run with `whitelist` PCIe devices, please pass the same in `dpdk-procinfo`

Comment: I have updated the answer to highlight the issue I am facing on running the ./dpdk-procinfo -- --stats command.

Comment: Ashwin once again it looks like a configuration issue, please answer the following 1. are you running primary with `--file-prefix`?, 2. are you running primary with whitelist PCI devices `-w`? 3. are you running primary with vdev instances?

Comment: Running primary with whitelist PCI devices.

Comment: then you have you pass same pci whitelist devices to dpdk-procinfo

Comment: Did try and run dpdk-procinfo with whitelist PCI devices, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I have been using the same and it has been working for me till date. 2 options, `option-1: share the primary command and confirm whether the application is compiled for static or shared` or `option-2: come online https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215826/dpdk-debug to debug`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I do not have enough reputation points to join the chat room, but I have update the question with the required information.

Comment: @AshwinKumar chat room id https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215826/dpdk-debug. if you are not able to reach you can reach me on mail or skype

Comment: I have mailed you. It would be nice if we can schedule a Skype call.

Comment: @AshwinKumar if you have found the answer helpful please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: the problem faced by @AshwinKumar was using wrong versions of primary and secondary. Suggested and show cases in live demo. Waiting for Ashwin to accept and close the ticket.