# dpdk proc info application generating version mismatch error

Tags: dpdk

If there are two versions of dpdk in the system.To make the primary and secondary dpdkproc info application to use the same dpdk version I have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to location of libdpdk.so and have run the dpdk sample application and dpdk-proc info of same version. Still Version mismatch error occurs.Please suggest some solution for this.

Comment: please update the information `1. DPDK versions, 2. how primary and secondary are compiled 3. if shared library result for ldd for the binary 4. what is result of primary using dpdk_version api call and 5. in dpdk-procinfo result of running with -v option`.

Comment: waiting for your update on the requested information. Happy to share some time for live debug too.

Comment: Thanks Vipin.I could solve the problem.Used the meson build dpdk sample application and dpdk proc info.Earlier the dpdk sample application was generated using makefile.

Comment: Nice So I will tag the previous answer to the current question, please accept and close the ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current update via comments, using the right DPDK version and tools (meson/makefile) the problem is resolved. This is similar to issue faced by @AshwinKumar and solution suggested [DPDK proc-info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559562/statistics-for-dpdk-interfaces/62566188?noredirect=1#comment125643254_62566188).

Note: always use the same dpdk version for building primary and secodnary and pass same device arguments too.